# In T-SQL, how to take a value of a row, based on conditions on a second column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
InvoiceNumber   AccountNumber   SumAmount
---------------------------------------------
1765            4150            20687.5000
1765            1100            20687.5000
1766            4150            41895.0000
1766            7730               20.0000
1797            4150                0.0000
1797            7730               20.0000
1797            1100             6652.3400
1797            4990             6652.3400
```

It's generated by this query:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber
    ,AccountNumber
    ,SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount
FROM vINVOICE_TABLE
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
    ,AccountNumber
ORDER BY InvoiceNumber
```

I want to apply this logic:

- If `SumAmount_Account 1 > SumAmount_Account2`, take `Account1`
- If `SumAmount_Account 1 == SumAmount_Account2`, take the higher-numbered account

So, the result should look like this:

```
InvoiceNumber   AccountNumber
---------------------------------
1765            4150
1766            4150
1797            4990
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could do it.

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, AccountNumber
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        Row_Number() OVER(
            Partition BY InvoiceNumber  
            ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC, AccountNumber DESC
        ) rowNumber,
        InvoiceNumber,
        AccountNumber
    FROM vINVOICE_TABLE
    GROUP BY InvoiceNumber, AccountNumber 
)inv
WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

Comment: The principle is right, but your order by within the `ROW_NUMBER` should be `ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC, AccountNumber DESC`. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fb40/2)